# Identify position of a word in a line stored in a variable using Powershell

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

I have a text file which is stored in a variable say $RC. It looks like below.

```
               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :        49        10         0         0         0         0
   Files :       212       170        37         0         5         2
   Bytes :   6.517 t   6.517 t    24.5 k         0  136.37 m       550
```

When I run

```
$RC | Measure-Object -Word -character -Line
```

it gives me the output as

```
Lines Words Characters Property
----- ----- ---------- --------
    4    34        280
```

if I run `$RC[1]`, it gives me the first line as:-

```
Dirs :        39         9         0         0         0         0
```

Now I want to navigate to 7th word in this above line (which is 0), how do I do that?

If that's not possible, my ultimate goal is to find values under Failed column (which are 0,5,136.37) in above text file and store them in another variable for comparison. How can it be done? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the command you're running to generate this output have an option to output as CSV?

Comment: No I already getting these 4 lines from a huge text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you don't want tot reinvent the wheel; using this [ConvertFrom-SourceTable](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable) cmdlet:

```
$RC = '
               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :        49        10         0         0         0         0
   Files :       212       170        37         0         5         2
   Bytes :   6.517 t   6.517 t    24.5 k         0  136.37 m       550'

$Data = ConvertFrom-SourceTable -Literal $RC
$Data |Format-Table

Total             Copied  Skipped Mismatch FAILED   Extras
-----             ------  ------- -------- ------   ------
Dirs :        49  10      0       0        0        0
Files :       212 170     37      0        5        2
Bytes :   6.517 t 6.517 t 24.5 k  0        136.37 m 550
```

Taking the first -zero based (`[0]`)- row and column `Extras`:

```
$Data[0].Extras
0
```

and taking the whole failed column using [Member-Access Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration):

```
$Data.Failed
0
5
136.37 m
```